# PHP: How to extract 6 weeks from current week?

Tags: php

i use the line below to create the current weeknumber. Now i want to have the current weeknumber minus 6 weeks, so i wrote the second line to complete that.

```
$date = date('2018-01-01');
$date_today = new DateTime($date);
$curr_weeknr = $date_today->format("W");
$six_weeks_ago = $curr_weeknr - 6;
```

At first sight it seems to be working, but when i set the date to 1 january 2018 the variable six_weeks_ago returns -6, but is needs to be 48.

Who can help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
$six_weeks_ago = ($curr_weeknr + 51 - 6) % 52 + 1;
```

Or:

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
$date->modify("-42 days");
$six_weeks_ago = $date->format("W");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, of course, is that `$curr_weeknr` is just a number. So if the current week number is 1, you'll get a negative number when you subtract.

Instead, you should let PHP do the date math for you. The [date_sub()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sub.php) function does what you want - it subtracts dates.

For example:

```
$six_weeks_ago = date_sub($date_today, date_interval_create_from_date_string("6 weeks"));
print $six_weeks_ago->format("W");
```

Comment: Don't you mean six weeks, not six days? ;-)

Comment: When i use this script and replace 'days' with 'weeks', i get the number 3 as return

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the comment [now answer] `$six_weeks_ago = ($curr_weeknr + 52 - 6) % 52;` I think it will be fastest for this purpose.

php does have the built in function though

[date_sub](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php)

from the manual:

```
<?php
    $date = date_create('2000-01-20');
    date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 days'));
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

changing the value:

```
<?php
    $date = date_create('2000-01-20');
    date_sub($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('6 weeks'));
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```